# Python sshtunnel module failed to connect mysql db

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, mysql-python, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect mysql db by ssh tunneling using python module "sshtunnel" but it is throwing an error like:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sql_user_name'@'172.45.678.910' (using password: YES)

here is my code

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (ssh_host,ssh_port),
    ssh_username = ssh_username,
    ssh_pkey = ssh_pkey_path,
    remote_bind_address=(sql_host, sql_port),
    local_bind_address=("127.0.0.1",8080)) as server:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=sql_host,user=sql_user_name,password=sql_pwd,db=db_name)
        myCursor = mydb.cursor()
```

my user_name and password is correct, I can successfully connect via sequal_pro using same credential and same ssh host, so why it is throwing an error here?
and in error message which ssh_host('172.45.678.910') it is showing is also different, I never use this ssh_host in code,in variable "ssh_host" the ip is different,
I tried all the solution available on the internet, but could not solve this issue

Comment: Since the example is not reproducible, I suggest to replace all variables in the `with` statement with the corresponding values and try to run that code. Then proceed with the debugging from there.

Comment: Shouldn't you use your local address (`127.0.0.1:8080`) that tunnels to the real address when connecting? Otherwise, MySQL connector has no way to know what tunnels are you creating.

Comment: programming error 1045 should have a description in the docs somewhere